# Google SignIn return an error when requesting offline access

Tags: android, google-signin

I have an app working for more than a year with the same code and now it stopped working.

Looking at the documentation, it looks the same, so I don't understand the error.

This is my code:

```
        String serverClientId = "9999999999-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"))
                .requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

I've sent the app for verification and I have permission for the scope **gmail.send**.

Using this code, on `onActivityResult` I receive this error inside `Intent data`:

```
googleSignInStatus - Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

And this exception at the line with `GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);`

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10
```

Any idea what changed? If I remove `requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId)`, it works, but  `account.getServerAuthCode()` returns null and I need it for offline access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to migrate my app to Firebase, delete app settings from Google Cloud Console and setup it on Firebase.

But, my web application settings need to continue on Google Cloud Console.

Why make things easy (all in one place) if you can difficult it.

## Thanks Google to make me spend 2 days on it.